# Accessing generalize-captured objects in lambda trailing return type

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, language-lawyer, trailing-return-type

```
int main()
{
    auto l = [x = 10]() -> decltype(x) {};
}
```

- [**clang++ 4.0** rejects this code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zsFICgiaMhCrIIwe) with the following error:

  ```
  error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
          auto l = [x = 10]() -> decltype(x) {};
                                          ^
  ```
- [**g++ 7** rejects this code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LXamt4MieU6n77Xs) with the following error:

  ```
  In function 'int main()':
  error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
    auto l = [x = 10]() -> decltype(x) {};
                                    ^
  error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
  In lambda function:
  warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
    auto l = [x = 10]() -> decltype(x) {};
                                    ^
  ```

**Is this a bug or is there something in the standard that explicitly prevents objects captured with the C++14 generalized syntax from being used in the lambda's trailing return type?**

---

Note that both compilers are happy with non-generalized captures:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    auto l = [x]() -> decltype(x) { return 0; };
}
```

Comment: `int` used to be a default return type, will gcc deduce any other type?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0: good catch. [It always "deduces" `int`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OivD8IYUT3Jq0720)... updating the question

Comment: There are some weird cases with `decltype` and lambdas, e.g. [this](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/6-VL5bzK6Ik).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Compilers behave as expected.

The standard defines lambda semantics as follows [expr.prim.lambda, section 1]:

> lambda-expression:
>
> ```
>    lambda-introducer lambda-declarator_opt compound-statement
> ```

Here *compound-statement* is just the body of lambda between {}, because everything else is included in *lambda-declarator*:

> lambda-declarator:
>
> ```
>    ( parameter-declaration-clause ) decl-specifier-seq_opt
>        exception-specification_opt attribute-specifier-seq_opt trailing-return-type_opt
> ```

Also, in section 12 of the same chapter, it's said that

> An init-capture behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form “auto init-capture ;”
>   whose declarative region is the lambda-expression’s compound-statement, except that:
>
> (12.1) — if the capture is by copy (see below), the non-static data member declared for the capture and the
>   variable are treated as two different ways of referring to the same object, which has the lifetime of the
>   non-static data member, and no additional copy and destruction is performed, and
>
> (12.2) — if the capture is by reference, the variable’s lifetime ends when the closure object’s lifetime ends.

So, in your first example, variable `x` scope is the lambda body only, not including the `decltype` expression. In the second example, obviously, `x` scope is the function `main`.

Comment: Thanks. This is slightly annoying but does make sense. I wonder if the rules could be relaxed to introduce `x` in the scope of the trailing return type...

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Consider creating a theme on the forum: https://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-future-proposals

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I just realized that the proposed change is breaking, so we probably won't see it implemented

Comment: [true.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/g9eAszk1SoGPA1Lf) This is so counter-intuitive though...